# How to create a black color overlay ontop of a video with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hello my fellow programmers,

So I am having a hard time creating a black color about 50% opacity overlay ontop of my  tags.

So check this out:

```
       <div class="section s1">
        <h1>"The Reaper"</h1>
        <h2>Limited edition watch</h2>
        <img src="assets\img\watch.png" alt="Watch">

        <div class="video-container">

            <video data-autoplay loop muted poster="assets\img\hero-1.jpg">
                <source src="assets\img\video.webm" type="video/WebM">
            </video>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.s1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.s1 h1{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: fadein 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Opera */
}

.s1 h2 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: fadein 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 5s;
    /* Opera */
}

.s1 img{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: slide 3s forwards;
    animation: slide 3s forwards;
}



.video-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:0;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

.s1 video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#video-container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.3));
}
```

So the question is: how would i create a black color overlay on my background video?
Feel free to ask any questions about my question.

Have a great day!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you should first make the background with the linear gradient.. Make it background-image: lineat-gradient.....